# Unablle to cure a login loop in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, login

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 about six times over the last two weeks.

Three of them on the same machine.

To tell the truth, the third installation was fine but I accidentally corrupted it by starting up the machine with a second drive (containing Mageia 5) still connected and unable to stop it in time.

The machine has AMD/ATI graphics, a four-core AMD processor, 8GB of RAM and a 2TB hard drive partitioned as 26GB for the root directory just over 9GB for swap space the balance for my /home directory.

The /home directory contains nearly 1TB of data.

Unable to cure the loop problem, I deleted the root partition (sda1) and reinstalled Ubuntu. I did not reformat the /home partition.

On both subsequent installations I ended up just getting to the login stage.

I have tried following suggestions already posted by similar sufferers but nothing has so far worked.

I would grateful for a solution.

Comment: Are you able to log in to one of the CLI virtual terminals (Ctrl-Alt-F1 thru Ctrl-Alt-F6)?